# Import txfonts integral

Tags: fonts, math-operators, integral, txfonts

I was trying to import the integral symbol from txfonts. In txfonts.sty I was able to find only multiple integrals of any type but the simple single one. I am sure I am missing something, can someone help me?

Comment: Perhaps I am wrong, but `txfonts` does not seem to have its own basic integral sign, but relies on the underlying math font. However, I am not an expert on this. I made this judgment studying both `txfonts.sty` as well as `symbols-a4.pdf` Welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Do you know where I can find that particular integral sign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a `\limits` version...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% WHOLE txfonts PACKAGE
%\usepackage{txfonts}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% JUST txfonts LARGE SYMBOLS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Math Extension %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
%\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{bx}{n}
%\DeclareFontSubstitution{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% JUST txfont INTEGRALS
%\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{txlargesyms}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{txlargesyms}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\txtxint}{\mathop}{txlargesyms}{82}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\txdsint}{\mathop}{txlargesyms}{90}

\def\txint{\txtxint\limits}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\begin{document}
\centerline{$\int_0^x \txint_0^x$}
\[
\int_0^x\txint_0^x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

And for a `\nolimits` version (a 2-letter change on a single line):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% WHOLE txfonts PACKAGE
%\usepackage{txfonts}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% JUST txfonts LARGE SYMBOLS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Math Extension %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
%\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}{OMX}{txex}{bx}{n}
%\DeclareFontSubstitution{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% JUST txfont INTEGRALS
%\DeclareFontFamily{OMX}{txlargesyms}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{txlargesyms}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\txtxint}{\mathop}{txlargesyms}{82}
%\DeclareMathSymbol{\txdsint}{\mathop}{txlargesyms}{90}

\def\txint{\txtxint\nolimits}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
\begin{document}
\centerline{$\int_0^x \txint_0^x$}
\[
\int_0^x\txint_0^x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! What about the position of the endpoints? Is it possible to have a "nontop" version?

Comment: @user182997 See my edit, please.

Comment: Perfection. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do it fully:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{txlargeoperators}{OMX}{txex}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{txlargeoperatorsA}{U}{txexa}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperators}{"52}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iintop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{33}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiintop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{35}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\iiiintop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{37}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\idotsintop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{39}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\ointop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperators}{"48}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{41}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\varointctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{43}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varointclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{45}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{64}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{66}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{72}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{74}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{68}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{70}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\oiiintclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{76}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varoiiintctrclockwiseop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{78}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\fintop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{62}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqiintop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{80}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sqiiintop}{\mathop}{txlargeoperatorsA}{82}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\int}{\DOTSI\intop\ilimits@}
\renewcommand{\iint}{\DOTSI\iintop\ilimits@}
\renewcommand{\iiint}{\DOTSI\iiintop\ilimits@}
\renewcommand{\iiiint}{\DOTSI\iiiintop\ilimits@}
\renewcommand{\idotsint}{\DOTSI\idotsintop\ilimits@}

\renewcommand{\oint}{\DOTSI\ointop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\oiint}{\DOTSI\oiintop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\oiiint}{\DOTSI\oiiintop\ilimits@}

\newcommand{\varointctrclockwise}{\DOTSI\varointctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\varointclockwise}{\DOTSI\varointclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\oiintctrclockwise}{\DOTSI\oiintctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\varoiintclockwise}{\DOTSI\varoiintclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\oiintclockwise}{\DOTSI\oiintclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\varoiintctrclockwise}{\DOTSI\varoiintctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\oiiintctrclockwise}{\DOTSI\oiiintctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\varoiiintclockwise}{\DOTSI\varoiiintclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\oiiintclockwise}{\DOTSI\oiiintclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\varoiiintctrclockwise}{\DOTSI\varoiiintctrclockwiseop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\fint}{\DOTSI\fintop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\sqiint}{\DOTSI\sqiintop\ilimits@}
\newcommand{\sqiiint}{\DOTSI\sqiiintop\ilimits@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\int
\iint
\iiint
\iiiint
\idotsint
\\
\oint
\oiint
\oiiint
\\
\varointctrclockwise
\varointclockwise
\oiintctrclockwise
\varoiintclockwise
\oiintclockwise
\varoiintctrclockwise
\oiiintctrclockwise
\varoiiintclockwise
\oiiintclockwise
\varoiiintctrclockwise
\\
\fint
\sqiint
\sqiiint
\end{gather}

\begin{gather}
\int_a^b
\iint_A
\iiint_A
\iiiint_A
\idotsint_A
\\
\oint_\gamma
\oiint_\gamma
\oiiint_\gamma
\\
\varointctrclockwise_\gamma
\varointclockwise_\gamma
\oiintctrclockwise_\gamma
\varoiintclockwise_\gamma
\oiintclockwise_\gamma
\varoiintctrclockwise_\gamma
\oiiintctrclockwise_\gamma
\varoiiintclockwise_\gamma
\oiiintclockwise_\gamma
\varoiiintctrclockwise_\gamma
\\
\fint_\gamma
\sqiint_\gamma
\sqiiint_\gamma
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I change `\usepackage{amsmath}` into `\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}` the output changes to

[image]

Of course you can change locally the behavior with `\limits` or `\nolimits`.